# Swing JMenu with a CheckBox

Tags: java, swing

I need to display a checkbox in a JMenu (mimicking what JCheckBoxMenuItem does, but at the Parent level).  This functionality does not seem to be a part of the Swing API, but I figured I could get it to work by overriding the JMenu API.

This is how I want it to look via a Mockup I threw together in Paint:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd7XB.png]

But I have been unsuccessful in getting the checkboxes to appear and I'm not sure how to force this behavior.

Here is an example of the code showing what I'm trying to do.  Right click anywhere in the frame:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class PopupMenuExample extends JFrame {
  JPopupMenu popupMenu;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {

        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
          if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            try {
              UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
          }
        }

        PopupMenuExample frame = new PopupMenuExample ();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

  }

  public PopupMenuExample () {

    popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

    popupMenu.add(createMenu("Displayed Items"));
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent Me) {
        if (Me.isPopupTrigger()) {
          popupMenu.show(Me.getComponent(), Me.getX(), Me.getY());
        }
      }
    });

  }

  public JMenu createMenu(String title) {
    JCheckBoxMenu m = new JCheckBoxMenu(title, true);

    JCheckBoxMenuItem tractorsMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Tractor", true);

    JCheckBoxMenu carsMenu = new JCheckBoxMenu("Cars", true);

    JCheckBoxMenuItem chevy = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Chevy", true);
    JCheckBoxMenuItem fusion = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Ford", true);
    JCheckBoxMenuItem tesla = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Tesla", true);

    carsMenu.add(chevy);
    carsMenu.add(fusion);
    carsMenu.add(tesla);

    JCheckBoxMenuItem tankMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Tank", true);

    m.add(tractorsMenuItem);
    m.add(carsMenu);
    m.add(tankMenuItem);


    return m;
  }


  // Trying to mimic how JCheckBoxMenuItem works:
  // https://github.com/Himansu-Nayak/java7-sourcecode/blob/master/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.java
  public static class JCheckBoxMenu extends JMenu {


    public JCheckBoxMenu(String text, boolean selected) {
      super(text);
      setModel(new JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel());
      setSelected(selected);
      setFocusable(false);

    }
  }


}
```

Comment: *"I need to display a checkbox in a JMenu (mimicking what JCheckBoxMenuItem does, but at the Parent level)."* ... ***Why?*** Putting my self in the shoes of the user of this software, I'm looking at the image above .. and have no idea what a tick next to Displayed Times, Tractor, Cars & Tank even means.

Comment: I have a UI display that shows (possibly) hundreds of widgets.  Each widget has an underlying tree-like hierarchy of items associated with it.  Their visibility can be controlled at any level of the hierarchy by right clicking on the widget and the context menu appears (similar to this mockup).  The checkbox indicates whether the visibility is enabled at that level.  Clicking the parent will toggle the children to match.

Comment: O..K. Why not use a `JTree` whose branches can be expanded or closed to reveal and hide the multitude of options? **Sidebar:** I, for one, have trouble navigating multi-level menu systems. E.G. I might already be several levels deep, then accidentally click just outside where I intended - causing the entire menu structure to disappear, as well as much frustration & swearing. A tree on the other hand is 'tolerant' of those sort of mistakes. Click the wrong place, and it's just one more click to get back to where you need to be.

Comment: I’m leaning towards the pop up menu because it is highly contextual to the widget the menu is triggered on.  I’m working in a WorldWind display with potentially hundreds or thousands of icons/widgets.  Correct me if I’m wrong, but the JTree would require a completely separate panel/frame?  Or is there some way to embed a jtree in pop up menu?

Comment: *"the JTree would require a completely separate panel/frame"* Technically, it could be put in a separate part of an existing panel, but I think that is still counter to what you seem to want for this GUI. *"..  is there some way to embed a jtree in pop up menu?"* I don't know, to be honest. But perhaps some clever person will see a way to provide this functionality in a way that is intuitive and easy to use, so I'll .. pop off now, and hope one of them drops by.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to agree with @Andrew Thompson in regards to utilising a `JMenu` for the job for the named reasons:

1. It isn't clear what a checkmark next to the menu actually means. (The same problem actually also applies to a tree with checkboxes).
2. Navigation isn't optimal using the menu structure e.g. the menu closes if you accidentally click at the wrong position. Also with the most lafs clicking a `JMenuItem` will actually close the whole `JPopupMenu`. Not ideal if you want to toggle multiple items.

The proposed solution of using a `JTree` for managing the state is the one I took. Because `JPopupMenu`s can't be focusable the popup needs to be created and handles explicitly. During the explanation I'll reference each class of the implementation which can be found at the end of my answer.

Because even with a `JTree` that displays the checkmark it can be ambiguous what it exactly means I'll be using a tristate approach where a given node in the tree can have the value `SELECTED`, `DELSELECTED` or `INDETERMINATE` where `INDETERMINATE` means that somewhere down the tree structure two leaf nodes have different values (Leafs are only allowed to have the `SELECTED` or `DESELECTED` state).

First we need the model for the tree. Here is simple implementation for a `TristateNode` that automatically manages the state of child and parent nodes. If a node that has children gets selected/deselected all descending nodes will automatically be selected/deselected (`TristateNode` and `TristateState`).

Now we need to provide the renderer and editor for the tree.
The renderer uses an icon to display the current `TristateState` of the node. I'm currently using solid colours, but you can do anything you like.
The editor doesn't actually do anything. Every time an edit request is sent it just iterates the state of the targeted node and the tells the tree to not edit. This way we don't have to provide an extra editing component. (`CheckboxTree`, `CheckBoxTreeRenderer`, `CheckBoxTreeEditor` and `TristateIcon`).

Now for the part where we display the popup to show the tree. Because it may be convenient to have the popup always visible I'll add a "Pin" button to the popup which migrates it to a full `JDialog`. If the popup/dialog is currently visible we simply switch the displayed component with the new one (`TreePopupManager` and `TreePopupContent`).

For a demo I have created a simple panel with 4 areas which can be selected using the mouse. By using the right mouse button the popup will be displayed at the mouse position. Clicking anywhere else will hide the popup. If the popup is currently pinned then focusing any of the components will automatically update the popup content.

Here is all the needed code for it:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(createContentPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static JComponent createContentPane() {
        return new DemoContent();
    }

    private static void drawRect(final Graphics g, final int x, final int y, final int w, final int h) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, 1);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 1, h);
        g.fillRect(x + w - 1, y, 1, h);
        g.fillRect(x, y + h - 1, w, 1);
    }

    private static class TreePopupManager {

        private static final TreePopupManager INSTANCE = new TreePopupManager();

        private final TreePopupContent contentPanel = new TreePopupContent(this::pin);
        private Popup popup;
        private Component owner;
        private Point lastPos;
        private JDialog dialog;

        public TreePopupManager() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(e -> {
                if (popup != null) {
                    if (e instanceof FocusEvent) {
                        Component oppositeComp = ((FocusEvent) e).getOppositeComponent();
                        Component comp = ((FocusEvent) e).getComponent();
                        int id = e.getID();
                        if (id == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST) {
                            if (oppositeComp == null
                                || !SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(oppositeComp, contentPanel)) {
                                hidePopup();
                            }
                        } else if (id == FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED) {
                            if (comp == null
                                || !SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(comp, contentPanel)) {
                                hidePopup();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (e instanceof MouseEvent && e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                        Component component = ((MouseEvent) e).getComponent();
                        if (!SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(component, contentPanel)) {
                            hidePopup();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }

        private void pin() {
            hidePopup();
            if (dialog == null) {
                dialog = new JDialog(owner != null ? SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(owner) : null);
                dialog.setContentPane(contentPanel);
                contentPanel.setPinned(true);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocation(lastPos);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        private void hidePopup() {
            if (popup != null) {
                popup.hide();
                popup = null;
            }
        }

        private void hideDialog() {
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
                dialog.dispose();
                dialog = null;
            }
        }

        public static TreePopupManager getInstance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        public boolean isPopupVisible() {
            return popup != null || dialog != null;
        }

        public void showPopup(final Component parent, final JTree content, final Point p, final String title) {
            contentPanel.setTitle(title);
            contentPanel.setContent(content);
            if (dialog != null && !dialog.isVisible()) {
                hideDialog();
            }
            if (popup == null && dialog == null) {
                contentPanel.setPinned(false);
                lastPos = p;
                owner = parent;
                popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(parent, contentPanel, p.x, p.y);
                popup.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TreePopupContent extends JPanel {

        private final JPanel view = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        private final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        private final JButton pinButton = new JButton("Pin");

        public TreePopupContent(final Runnable onPin) {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(view) {
                @Override
                public void setBorder(final Border border) {}
            };
            add(scrollPane);
            Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
            box.add(label);
            box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            pinButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            pinButton.setFocusable(false);
            pinButton.setFocusPainted(false);
            pinButton.addActionListener(e -> onPin.run());

            box.add(pinButton);
            box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
            add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

        public void setPinned(final boolean pinned) {
            pinButton.setVisible(!pinned);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            super.updateUI();
            setBorder(new JPopupMenu().getBorder());
        }

        public void setTitle(final String title) {
            label.setText(title);
        }

        public void setContent(final JComponent content) {
            setBackground(content.getBackground());
            view.removeAll();
            view.add(content);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            Dimension pref = view.getPreferredSize();
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Math.max(pref.width, 100) + 10,
                                           Math.max(pref.height, 200) + 10));
        }
    }

    private static class DemoContent extends JPanel {

        private DemoContent() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
            add(new DemoContentPanel(new CheckBoxTree(populate(new TristateNode("root1"), 1, 1))));
            add(new DemoContentPanel(new CheckBoxTree(populate(new TristateNode("root2"), 2, 2))));
            add(new DemoContentPanel(new CheckBoxTree(populate(new TristateNode("root3"), 3, 3))));
            add(new DemoContentPanel(new CheckBoxTree(populate(new TristateNode("root4"), 4, 4))));
        }

        private TristateNode populate(final TristateNode node, final int count, final int depth) {
            if (depth == 0) return node;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                node.add(populate(new TristateNode("Node-" + depth + "-" + i), count, depth - 1));
            }
            return node;
        }
    }

    private static class DemoContentPanel extends JPanel {

        private final CheckBoxTree tree;

        private DemoContentPanel(final CheckBoxTree tree) {
            this.tree = tree;
            setFocusable(true);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
                    requestFocus();
                    onMousePressed(e);
                }
            });
            addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(final FocusEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(final FocusEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (hasFocus()) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            drawRect(g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        protected void onMousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                TreePopupManager manager = TreePopupManager.getInstance();
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) || manager.isPopupVisible()) {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, this);
                    manager.showPopup(this, tree, p, "Tree");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static class CheckBoxTree extends JTree {

        public CheckBoxTree(final TristateNode root) {
            super(root);
            setShowsRootHandles(true);
            setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxTreeRenderer());
            setCellEditor(new CheckBoxTreeEditor(this));
            setEditable(true);
        }
    }

    private static class CheckBoxTreeRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        private final TristateIcon icon = new TristateIcon();

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(final JTree tree, final Object value, final boolean sel,
                                                      final boolean expanded, final boolean leaf,
                                                      final int row, final boolean hasFocus) {
            Component component = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            JLabel label = (JLabel) component; // DefaultTreeCellRenderer uses JLabel as its renderer;
            TristateNode node = (TristateNode) value;
            label.setText(node.getLabel());
            label.setIcon(icon);
            icon.setState(node.getState());
            return label;
        }
    }

    private static class CheckBoxTreeEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

        private final JTree tree;

        public CheckBoxTreeEditor(final JTree tree) {
            this.tree = tree;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(final JTree tree, final Object value,
                                                    final boolean isSelected,
                                                    final boolean expanded,
                                                    final boolean leaf, final int row) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return ((TristateNode) tree.getEditingPath().getLastPathComponent()).getState();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(final EventObject anEvent) {
            if (!(anEvent instanceof InputEvent)) return false;
            InputEvent event = (InputEvent) anEvent;
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (!(source instanceof JTree)) return false;
            JTree tree = (JTree) source;
            Object value = null;
            if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                Point p = ((MouseEvent) event).getPoint();
                TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(p.x, p.y);
                if (path != null) {
                    value = path.getLastPathComponent();
                }
            } else {
                value = tree.getLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
            }
            if (value instanceof TristateNode) {
                ((TristateNode) value).iterateState();
                tree.repaint();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(final EventObject anEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelCellEditing() {}

        @Override
        public void addCellEditorListener(final CellEditorListener l) {}

        @Override
        public void removeCellEditorListener(final CellEditorListener l) {}
    }

    private static class TristateNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
        private String label;

        public TristateNode() {
            this(null);
        }

        public TristateNode(final String label) {
            this(label, TristateState.DESELECTED);
        }

        public TristateNode(final String label, final TristateState state) {
            this(label, state, true);
        }

        public TristateNode(final String label, final TristateState state, final boolean allowsChildren) {
            super();
            parent = null;
            this.allowsChildren = allowsChildren;
            this.userObject = state;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(final MutableTreeNode newChild) {
            if (!(newChild instanceof TristateNode)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only children of type TristateTreeNode are allowed.");
            }
            super.add(newChild);
        }

        public TristateState getState() {
            return getUserObject();
        }

        public void setState(final TristateState state) {
            setState(state, false, false);
        }

        private void setState(final TristateState state, final boolean invokedByParent, final boolean invokedByChild) {
            if (isLeaf() && state == TristateState.INDETERMINATE) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Leaf nodes cannot have an indeterminate state");
            }
            super.setUserObject(state);
            if (!isLeaf() && !invokedByChild) {
                if (state != TristateState.INDETERMINATE) {
                    for (TreeNode node : children) {
                        if (node instanceof TristateNode) {
                            ((TristateNode) node).setState(state, true, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!invokedByParent) {
                Object treeNode = getParent();
                if (treeNode instanceof TristateNode) {
                    ((TristateNode) treeNode).setState(((TristateNode) treeNode).getEffectiveState(), false, true);
                }
            }
        }

        public void setSelected(final boolean selected) {
            this.userObject = selected;
        }

        @Override
        public TristateState getUserObject() {
            return (TristateState) super.getUserObject();
        }

        @Override
        public void setUserObject(final Object userObject) {
            if (!(userObject instanceof TristateState)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only values of type TristateState are allowed but got "
                                                   + userObject);
            }
            setState((TristateState) userObject);
        }

        public TristateState getEffectiveState() {
            if (isLeaf()) return getState();
            TristateState state = null;
            for (TreeNode node : children) {
                if (node instanceof TristateNode) {
                    TristateState nodeState = ((TristateNode) node).getState();
                    if (state == null) state = nodeState;
                    if (state != nodeState) {
                        state = TristateState.INDETERMINATE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return state != null ? state : TristateState.DESELECTED;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(final String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public void iterateState() {
            TristateState state = getState();
            switch (state) {
                case DESELECTED :
                    setState(TristateState.SELECTED);
                    break;
                case SELECTED :
                    setState(TristateState.DESELECTED);
                    break;
                case INDETERMINATE :
                    setState(state.next());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private enum TristateState {
        DESELECTED() {
            @Override
            public TristateState next() {
                return INDETERMINATE;
            }
        },
        SELECTED() {
            @Override
            public TristateState next() {
                return DESELECTED;
            }
        },
        INDETERMINATE() {
            @Override
            public TristateState next() {
                return SELECTED;
            }
        };

        public abstract TristateState next();
    }

    private static class TristateIcon implements Icon {

        private TristateState state = TristateState.DESELECTED;

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y) {
            switch (state) {
                case DESELECTED :
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case SELECTED :
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case INDETERMINATE :
                    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    break;
                default :
                    return;
            }
            g.fillRect(x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
        }

        public void setState(final TristateState state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return 16;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return 16;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how the result looks like:

[image: Result]

Comment: wow! that's pretty great.  You must be a Swing Wizard. I like the "Pin" function.  Is there a way to make the Pin function keep the same exact window and just wrap it in a frame? (Or at least make it look that way to the user by having it in the same location?)

Comment: Instead of using a dialog you could use a `JWindow` And handle the dragging of the window yourself with a combination of MouseListener and MouseMotionListener on the “title area”

Comment: I awarded a bounty based on providing a solution rather than attempting to answer the original question. But I have to add: that animated screen shot is *pretty cool!*  :)